# Azure AD OAuth2.0 Transient Errors (AADSTS90090)

Tags: security, authentication, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD app which was working fine yesterday. But today, the response from the sign in page (the one with the code param), is returning an error and error_description params, and no code param. The values are:

**error**: temporarily_unavailable

**error_description**: AADSTS90090: A
   transient error has occurred. Please try again. Trace ID: [unid]
   Correlation ID: [unid] Timestamp: 2015-08-12 08:44:06Z

A few Googles says this is a temporary error, which should "go away soon", but given this is an authentication request, I would expect such transient errors to be resolved in seconds, or minutes at a maximum, and this has now been happening for hours.

Questions:

- Is this something that happens regularly?
- How long should it take to be resolved?
- Is there anything (other than display an error message) I can do my end to handle this?

Any further information appreciated.

Comment: Update: The login had started working again now